# wordpress incorrect subdirectory goes to "broken home page"

Tags: wordpress, url, subdirectory

I have just finished a website (www.pickmixmagazine.com). It works fine, but the problem I have is that if I go to a non-existent subdirectory e.g. www.pickmixmagazine.com/unknownsubdomain then it will go to a broken version of the home page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: I was so silly, I forgot to add my 404.php :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a 404.php page.